# PlatformIO Possible key upload_flags & upload_command string option

Tags: configuration, platformio

I work with STM32F429ZI and PlatformIO and i need to upload firmware to specific address like 0x08020000 for example. And I can't find in docs on platformio which key for upload_flags I can use for it, or how I can modify upload_command for it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Right solution is add mbed_app.json to your project root with:

```
{
    "target_overrides": {
        "*": {
        "target.mbed_app_start" : "0x08020000",
        "target.mbed_app_size" :  "0x000A0000"
        }
    }
}
```

https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os/v5.15/reference/bootloader-configuration.html

This parameters expand to:

```
MEMORY
{
  FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x8020000, LENGTH = 0xa0000
...
}
```

on your .ld script and you don't need to change upload_flags and upload_command.